# Excel Treating VBA button as Shape

Tags: vba, excel, shapes, powerpoint

I created a macro to cycle through multiple columns, create a scatter plot, export that plot to powerpoint on a specific slide, delete the original chart in excel and repeat on a loop.

The problem arises when I include a Macro Button as it treats the button as a Shape and therefore it export a picture of the button to the powerpoint as well. Is there another way to define the button as something other than a shape so that this will not occur?

```
Sub Export_To_PowerPoint_JAH()
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+Shift+M

On Error Resume Next

Dim Shape As Shape
Dim PP As PowerPoint.Application
Dim PPpres As PowerPoint.Presentation

'Create a PP application and make it visible
Set PP = New PowerPoint.Application
PP.Visible = msoCTrue

'Open the presentation you wish to copy to
'Set PPpres = PP.Presentations.Open("C:\Users\jh307836\Documents\Excel Test.pptx")
Set PPpres = PP.Presentations.Open(Range("B1").Value)

i = 0
A = 0

Do

If Cells(i + 5, 3) = "" Then
Exit Do
End If

'Create Chart
'----------------------------------------------------
'Create Range for Y
    Dim rng1Y As Range, rng2Y As Range
    Dim Y_Range As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Scatter Plots")
    Set rng1Y = .Cells(2, A + 5)
    Set rng2Y = .Cells(2, A + 5).End(xlDown)

        Set Y_Range = .Range(rng1Y.Address & ":" & rng2Y.Address)
        Y_Range.Select

    End With

' Create Range for X
    Dim rng1X As Range, rng2X As Range
    Dim X_Range As Range

With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Scatter Plots")
    Set rng1X = .Cells(2, A + 6)
    Set rng2X = .Cells(2, A + 6).End(xlDown)

        Set X_Range = .Range(rng1X.Address & ":" & rng2X.Address)
        X_Range.Select

    End With

'Build chart

Dim Sh As Worksheet
Dim chrt As Chart

Set chrt = Nothing
Set Sh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Scatter Plots")
Set chrt = Sh.Shapes.AddChart.Chart
With chrt

        'Data
        .ChartType = xlXYScatter
        .SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        .SeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""Scatter Chart"""
        .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = X_Range
        .SeriesCollection(1).Values = Y_Range


        'Titles
        .HasTitle = True
        .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = Cells(i + 5, 2).Value
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = Cells(1, A + 6).Value
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
        .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = Cells(1, A + 5).Value
        .Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = True

        'Formatting
        .Axes(xlCategory).HasMinorGridlines = False
        .Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = True
        .Axes(xlValue).HasMinorGridlines = False
        .HasLegend = False

'-----------------------------------------------------
'Hide Button From Shape set
ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1").Visible = False
'Set the shape you want to copy (1) means current plot "random"
Set Shape = Worksheets("Scatter Plots").Shapes(1)

'Copy the shape
Shape.Copy

'Define Slide #
Z = Cells(i + 5, 3).Value

'Paste on the "Z" slide
'PPpres.Slides(Z).Shapes.Paste

'Pastes Shape to Z slide and Repositions/ Resizes shape
With PPpres.Slides(Z)
    .Shapes.Paste
    With .Shapes(.Shapes.Count)
        .LockAspectRatio = msoTrue
        .Left = Range("B20").Value
        .Top = Range("B21").Value
        .Height = Range("A17").Value
    End With
End With

'Deletes last shape
Shape.Delete

'Clears shape from clipboard
Set Shape = Nothing

i = i + 1
A = A + 3

End With

Loop

MsgBox ("Please Check Your Powerpoint")

End Sub
```

Comment: Maybe try an if something like `if shape.name<>"Button1" then`...or whatever the button name is

Comment: You need to post your code: without knowing how you're exporting to PPT I'm not sure how we can suggest changes....

Comment: Hide the `Shape` before you export.

Comment: I tried the if statement and unfortunately that did not work. For some reason it made everything go haywire and it pastes whatever was on my clipboard last onto every slide. I also tried hiding the shape but that pasted a blank place onto the first slide (as if it is seeing the shape as a blank but still connecting it to a position so it pastes a blank  place where my first chart goes and then pastes everything else offset by one position. Here is my code including the hiding of the button.

Comment: Hiding the shape won't remove it from the shapes collection; if it's the first shape on the sheet before adding the chart, it'll STILL be the first shape after, so copying the first shape would give you the button.  Have you tried cht.Copy instead?

Answer (score 0):

- Remove `On Error Resume Next`. This is quite dangerous, as it ignores the errors on your code.
- The Shape is copied with `Shape.Copy`.

Thus, remove this line and write:

```
If Not IsItButton(shape.name) Then Shape.Copy
```

To make it work, add this function:

```
Public Function IsItButton(nameStr As String) As Boolean    
    IsItButton = CBool(lcase(Left(nameStr, Len("button"))) = "button")    
End Function
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help, the button is not being copied now which is good, but it is being deleted because of shape.delete. I added to this     If not IsItButton(shape.name) then shape.delete, but now it does not delete any of the charts after they are pasted and it just pastes my last chart onto every slide. Any idea why this is?

Comment: @Jordan - It is tough to say from the code. What I can advise is to remove `On Error Resume Next` and start debugging the code with F8. Then the error will appear. Most probably, it is taking old `shape`. Try to write `If-Else-End If` condition, to avoid this scenario.